# Using SearchQuerySet haystack API without django models and nutch

Tags: django, nutch, django-haystack

Morning all,

This past week I have been experimenting with different search engines and indexing tools and have come across a problem. I have a django site that is all static pages. I have used nutch to scrape the site and send the results to a solr index. I would like to use haystack for getting the results of the search, but I have run into a few problems.

The first problem is that I do not have any models in the site, and therefor the tutorial that haystack has set up is useless. I already have the index set up in solr and would just like to use the SearchQuerySet API to search it.

The first thing I tried was adding these lines to the solr index to get it to work:

```
    <field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

However, after that, when I try to use the API to search, I get the following error on the django page:

```
   "KeyError at /search/" 'django_ct'
```

I've heard from people, that you have to add those keys to the schema.xml in solr in order to be able to use the SearchQuerySet without having models.

If someone could provide further information or help on what I should do next, that would be great.

Thanks

P.S here is my traceback

```
  Traceback:
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  136.                     response = response.render()
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  104.             self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         content = template.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  837.         return node.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  837.         return node.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  837.         return node.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  837.         return node.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  837.         return node.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  837.         return node.render(context)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  145.         len_values = len(values)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/src/stuff/haystack/query.py" in __len__
  84.             self._result_count = self.query.get_count()
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/src/stuff/haystack/backends/__init__.py" in get_count
  459.                 self.run()
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/src/stuff/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py" in run
  667.         results = self.backend.search(final_query, **search_kwargs)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/src/stuff/haystack/backends/__init__.py" in wrapper
  27.             return func(obj, query_string, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/src/stuff/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py" in search
  257.         return self._process_results(raw_results, highlight=highlight, result_class=result_class, distance_point=distance_point)
  File "/home/dave/virtualenvs/stuff/src/stuff/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py" in _process_results
  355.             app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT].split('.')
```

Exception Type: KeyError at /search/
Exception Value: 'django_ct'